# Use AMS Serializer as part of another JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Is there anyway to use an existing ActiveModel::Serializer class to create a hash?

I use AMS in a certain part of my app to handle rendering the entire JSON object, but in another part I want to be able to build the json object by hand. ie.

```
hash = {
  bla_bla: {
    # these attributes should be whatever is defined in the Serializer 
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can get the hash output of a serializer with `serializer.serializable_hash`

Comment: @max That's true - but if I wanted to use that I'd have to do something like `serializer = BlaSerializer.new(my_bla); adapter = FlattenJson.new(serializer)` which I'd like to avoid.  I'm wondering if there is a method to just get the defaults/configured values like `render json: my_bla` does.

Comment: @max cont... the reason being, I want to do this multiple times, and I don't want to have to manually write the serializer names, specify the adapter, check if it's a collection so that I wrap it with the ArraySerializer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found so far is to do this:

```
def serialize_data(resources)
  serializer_klass = ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(resources)
  serializer = serializer_klass.new(resources)
  adapter = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::FlattenJson.new(serializer)
  adapter.serializable_hash
end
```

which gives you the resources attributes as a hash.

In my example I would use this like

```
hash = {
  bla: serialize_data(Bla.first)
}
```